# what package should be imported when using @Before @After cucumber Hooks

Tags: maven, hook, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I'm using Cucumber and Junit for my Maven Project. When I tried to create Cucumber Hooks with @After or @Before annotation and imported cucumber.api.java.Before; package, it didnt work. It says this is deprecated. Can someone tell me what annotation I can use for running the steps before every scenario or if I should import any other package for cucumber hooks? I tried importing io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions as well. It didn't work.

I'm using io.cucumber dependencies version 4.8.1. With this version, it shows @After @Before cucumber hooks annotation deprecated but With version 2.0.0,it doesn't show deprecated.

Could someone help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Adapt your imports' packages. There is:

- [`cucumber.api.java.After`](https://javadoc.io/static/io.cucumber/cucumber-java/4.8.1/cucumber/api/java/After.html) which is deprecated
- [`io.cucumber.java.After`](https://javadoc.io/static/io.cucumber/cucumber-java/4.8.1/io/cucumber/java/After.html) which is not

The same applies to `Before`.

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to add below dependency in POM.xml file

<dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

Import below packages:

import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;
```

Comment: Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.